# Ruby Selenium Webdriver - Sleep instead of Wait

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the **Ruby** and **selenium-webdriver** gem to create a web-crawling/scraping script. I am pretty much completed on project but stuck at a point
The site I am scraping uses in page call to server and displays a string, the problem is it displays 50% of times not 100%. So I need to loop the get function until it displays the string.

I have used **Implicit & Explicit Wait**, but they both work in a condition >> Wait Until >> condition >> {either continues after condition is **TRUE** or **Throws an exception**} which will break my script in 50% of cases

```
#throws exception after timout

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) 
wait.until { driver.find_element(:id, 'message').displayed? }
```

What I need is >> Sleep Until >> Condition {Either Continue after condition is **true** or execute code to call string again

```
#continues to next block of code after timout

sleep = Selenium::WebDriver::Sleep.new(:timeout => 10) 
sleep.until { driver.find_element(:id, 'message').displayed? } do
   ##RUN CODE TO CALL THE STRING AGAIN##
end
```

Well I can use normal *sleep* *10* and works fine but it is wastage of time in case the call returned string in first place

```
#normal Sleep

sleep 10
driver.find_element(:id, 'message').displayed?
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby so can't help you with code, but you can build a function that will run until the element is displayed or the amount of time passed. If the element is displayed the function will return true immediately.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I had thought of that solution, but problem is after the execution of the code to get the element(message) it must wait for maximum 10 seconds (amount of time usually a server can take to reply) & minimum of 0 seconds (if server  replies in less than 10 seconds) in order to save wastage of time

Comment: You can do something like `start = Time.now` and in the loop add condition `Time.now - start > 10`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Method will either interrupt waiting when condition is truthy,
# or it will throw Timeout error after N seconds
def wait_until(timeout = DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME)
  Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
    sleep(0.1) until value = yield
    value
  end
end

# usage
wait_until(10) { driver.find_element(:id, 'message').displayed? }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I solved it myself ;) Thanks for your help guys, there is no such thing "sleep.until" in selenium. The solution was to handle the exception and act accordingly.

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)

def run 
  ##code to retrieve message

  begin
    wait.until { driver.find_element(:id, 'message').displayed? } #check if message received
  rescue
    ##this block get's executed if there is any kind of exception error
    run
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

**My Solution**

While your solution does work, I would like to propose another solution:

```rb
def element_is_displayed?(by, value)

  # Can I find any elements on the page matching what I've been given?
  if driver.find_elements({by => value})[0] != nil
    # Got a match, is it displayed?
    driver.find_element({by => value}).displayed?
  else
    # No matches found
    false 
  end
end

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until { element_is_displayed?("id", "message") }
```

**The Explanation**

The `element_is_displayed?` function will attempt to find at least 1 match of the values given, if it can't find a match, or the element is not displayed, it will do a loop within the `wait.until`

Because this function always returns a boolean value, it's suited for use inside of the selenium `wait.until` method, which will only return when either the timeout is satisfied, or there is a truthy value returned.

Another plus is that this function is reusable: keeping the function as configurable as possible, you'll still be able to find elements by anything native to selenium (css, id, xpath, etc).

It also means that if the element doesn't exist on the page at all for some reason (browser hasn't loaded the page, for instance), then the function won't constantly loop (it looks likely that yours could do this for a few hours, because it will rescue the "element not found" error and run itself again).

Hope this helps.